# Limit image width and heigth, if manual scale exceeds page width or height

Tags: width, height, scale

### Objective

I have a few images which I would prefer to all have the same scaling, with the exception of images that are too wide or too tall to fit on a single page.

### Code to Limit Image Width

```
% Auto scale images
\makeatletter
\newbox\image@box%
\newdimen\image@width%
\newdimen\image@height%
\newcommand\IncludeGraphics[2][\@empty]{%
  \setbox\image@box=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  %\setbox\image@box=\vbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \image@width\wd\image@box%
  \image@height\ht\image@box%
  \ifdim \image@width>\linewidth%
    \setbox\image@box=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}}%
    \box\image@box%
  \else
    \ifdim \image@height>0.8\textheight%
       \setbox\image@box=\vbox{\includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight]{#2}}%
     \box\image@box%    
     \else%
       \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
     \fi%
  \fi%
}
```

This auto scales the image to whatever I set it in `\IncludeGraphics` e.g. `\scale=0.7`, unless the image is wider than the page, in which case the image width is set to `width=\linewidth`.

### Code to Limit Image Height

It is the same code, except with the `%\setbox\image@box=\vbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%` line uncommented.

### Issue

If the image height limitation is on, the image width limitation is lost.

### Doubts

I assume this issue could be resolved by creating two `image@box` things/objects/variables (or what they actually are). As it seems defining the `image@box=\hbox` overwrites the `image@box=\vbox`. However, I have not yet been successfull at creating two of such objects such that both the image width and height are limited (whilst still allowing for a default scaling).

### Question

Hence, I would like to ask: How can I include an additional if-condition that limits the image height if it exceeds the page height (whilst scaling to default scale otherwise (if the imagewidth is not broader than the `\linewidth`))?

Comment: please post test files not fragments especially fragments using undefined commands, where is `\elifdim` defined?

Comment: Thank you, I did not know `ifdim` was defined, `elifdim` was defined in my imagination/not defined apparently. I replaced `\elifdim` with another `\ifdim` and a separate `else` statement, and updated the error message accordingly. I think another remaining fragment may be `image@height`. I did not yet figure out how to define that ((I assume) analogous to `\image@width\wd\image@box`).